# Is it possible to iterate through multiple files on the node machine using Ansible playbook and search n replace a particular line

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts, ansible-template

Is there a module/way to iterate over multiple files?

Use Case:

There are multiple `.conf` files

```
/opt/a1.conf

/opt/a2.conf

/var/app1/conf/a3.conf

/etc/a4.conf
```

Is there a module or a way to iterate over multiple files and search if a particular string exists in these files. The string will remain the same.

The "lineinfile" module help you search a single file but I would like to know if there is a way to iterate over multiple files and search for this string and replace it with a different values

**My Current playbook Contents for a single file:**

```
    - name: Modify line to include Timeout
      become: yes
      become_method: sudo
        lineinfile:
        path: /tmp/httpd.conf
        regexp: 'http\s+Timeout\s+\='
        line: 'http Timeout = 10'
        backup: yes
```

> The above can be used only for a single file.

**Alternatively, we can use some kind of shell command to do it but is there an Ansible way to achieve this?**

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried iterating thru `loop` parameter?

```
- name: Modify line to include Timeout
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  lineinfile:
    path: "{{ item }}"
    regexp: 'http\s+Timeout\s+\='
    line: 'http Timeout = 10'
    backup: yes
  loop:
    - /opt/a1.conf
    - /opt/a2.conf
    - /var/app1/conf/a3.conf
    - /etc/a4.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

You use with_items directive to transvere of the file, or you can use Jinja scripts look for the string something like below:

```
files: 
  - /opt/a1.conf
  - /opt/a2.conf
  - /var/app1/conf/a3.conf
  - /etc/a4.conf
```

`{% for item in files %} {{item.find('string')}} {% endfor %}`

Comment: you can use the ansible loop_control to cycle the variables, Ansible is deprecating with_items in future releases